# Android Simple Timer/Timertask issue

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I am trying to get a basic timer to work on Android and I have the following code in the onCreate() method:

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    Timer time = new Timer();     

    time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            timesince++;
            editText.setText("Timeran:"+timesince);
            Log.d("TIMER", "TimerTask run");
        }}, 0, 1000);
```

So hopefully it would update the textbox with a increasing value (timesince) -which is declared at top of program, along with editText...

However, (although I get no compile issues) when I run it on the emulator it does not work at all. App says 'blahblahblah has stopped working...'

Am I doing Timers wrong? What am I missing?

Thanks alot.

(P.S. App works fine if this code is removed so I know there is an issue with this section.)

EDIT: I believe this is my logcat output, sorry for wall of text:

```
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:3939)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:714)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:763)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4012)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8454)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.widget.TextView.invalidateCursor(TextView.java:4319)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.widget.TextView.spanChange(TextView.java:7670)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onSpanAdded(TextView.java:8020)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendSpanAdded(SpannableStringBuilder.java:898)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:614)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:520)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:87)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.initialize(ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:302)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3244)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3110)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:78)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3085)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at com.example.cultivation.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:54)
10-11 03:40:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(561):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

This is the problem

You have to move the portion of the background task that updates the ui onto the main thread or create the mHandler in your UI thread;

**Update:**

Updating the UI from a Timer : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really know what that means; I thought onCreate() on my main.java thing would be part of the main thread? -Where should I put this timer code then?

Answer (score 2):

or use handler to run update the textview:

```
     private final Runnable mRunnable1 = new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
        timesince++;
        editText.setText("Timeran:"+timesince);
        Log.d("TIMER", "TimerTask run");

 mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable1, 1000);
 }

 };
```

and also call this line in `OnCreate()` method  `mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable1, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the `TextView` from a UI thread. Try to use a handler. Here you can find a good article on that. [Update textview with the help of Handler](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html)

Answer (score 0):

do the following:

declare Timer as global variable and call the timer function in a method like the following:

```
   public void startThread(){
    time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        timesince++;
        editText.setText("Timeran:"+timesince);
        Log.d("TIMER", "TimerTask run");
    }}, 0, 1000);
    }
```

and call this `startThread()` function in `onCreate()`